# How to stop focus being invoked for lowest tab index control when initializecomponent() is called?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

When I open new form all the controls are initialized by `InitializeComponent`() in the constructor of form. This invokes `Focus()` for control which has lowest tab index (tried increasing each tab index by one, starting from 1, but it still invokes control with tab index 1). How can I stop `Focus()` being called on `InitializeComponent()` so after, when I hit right array on key, it goes to lowest tab index and not already on lowest tab index + 1?

Comment: Sigh.  You want *something* to have the focus at first.  Give it TabIndex 1.  You want *something else* to have the focus when you press the right cursor key, give it TabIndex 2.  Etcetera.  It isn't complicated and doesn't require code.  If you want to write code anyway then use the control's Select() method.

Comment: I know that @HansPassant. The problem is this Focus() being invoked. I guess Adriano's answer will do with custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I stop Focus() being called on InitializeComponent()

You can't. In WinForms the focus will always go to the first control (according to tab index) enabled and selectable. Focus will be on Form itself only if there isn't any selectable (and enabled) control within it.

> so after, when I hit right array on key, it goes to lowest tab index and not already on lowest tab index + 1

It's not very clear what you mean. You can change tab order to select which controll will be first one to be selected when `Form` is open. If you want to *hide* focus what you can do is to derive your own custom control, put it in the `Form` and set it with lowest tab index. It'll be focused one but user won't see it and it'll not interact (for example with keyboard):

```
class DummyFocusControl : Control {
    DummyFocusControl() {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
    }
}
```

Then you can always force a control to become focused using `Focus()` or `Select()` methods (see MSDN for details about them, they're slightly different):

```
anotherControl.Focus(); // anotherControll will receive keyboard focus
```